# How to find my driver module associated modules

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, broadcom, nvme

I have a Network interface card which is having RDMA capability, How to find the RDMA module installed or loaded with the NIC driver module?

My Broadcom driver.

```
modinfo bnxt_en
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64/updates/bnxt_en.ko
version:        1.10.2-224.0.157.0
description:    Broadcom NetXtreme-C/E/S network driver
license:        GPL
rhelversion:    8.6
srcversion:     533BB7E5866E52F63B9ACCB
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000D800sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001809sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001808sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001807sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001806sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016DCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016CBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016BDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001609sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001607sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001606sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000D804sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000D802sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001805sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001804sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001803sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001802sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001801sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001800sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001752sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001751sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001750sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016F1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016F0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016EFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016EEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016EDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016ECsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016EBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016EAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016E2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016DFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016DEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016D0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016CFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016CDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016CCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016CAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000016C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001614sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001605sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00001604sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:
name:           bnxt_en`enter code here`
vermagic:       4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

How I can verify my nvme_rdma module also loaded with above NIC or rdma is supported properlly for above NIC.

Similarly

for Mellanox NIC
the NIC driver is

```
modinfo mlx5_core
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/extra/mlnx-ofa_kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core/mlx5_core.ko
version:        5.1-2.5.8
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Mellanox 5th generation network adapters (ConnectX series) core driver
author:         Eli Cohen <eli@mellanox.com>
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.6
srcversion:     FBF53BFBCF621F2C47602D4
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000A2D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000A2D3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000A2D2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001021sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000101Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000101Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000101Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000101Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000101Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d0000101Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001019sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001018sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001017sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001016sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001015sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001014sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000015B3d00001013sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mlx_compat,mdev,devlink,ptp,mlxfw
vermagic:       3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           guids:charp
parm:           node_guid:guids configuration. This module parameter will be obsolete!
parm:           num_of_groups:Eswitch offloads number of big groups in FDB table. Valid range 1 - 1024. Default 4 (uint)
parm:           debug_mask:debug mask: 1 = dump cmd data, 2 = dump cmd exec time, 3 = both. Default=0 (uint)
parm:           prof_sel:profile selector. Valid range 0 - 3 (uint)
parm:           probe_vf:probe VFs or not, 0 = not probe, 1 = probe. Default = 1 (bool)
[root@dhcp-10-206-133-164 ~]# modinfo nvme-rdma
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/extra/mlnx-nvme/host/nvme-rdma.ko
license:        GPL v2
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.6
srcversion:     C9065DB6209669124255FDE
depends:        mlx_compat,rdma_cm,ib_core,nvme-core,nvme-fabrics
vermagic:       3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           register_always:Use memory registration even for contiguous memory regions (bool)
```

how I can find nvme-rdma also support also there for below NIC.

adding nvme-rdma

```
modinfo nvme-rdma
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/extra/mlnx-nvme/host/nvme-rdma.ko
license:        GPL v2
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.6
srcversion:     C9065DB6209669124255FDE
depends:        mlx_compat,rdma_cm,ib_core,nvme-core,nvme-fabrics
vermagic:       3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           register_always:Use memory registration even for contiguous memory regions (bool)
```

the OS-details

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```

Please help someone.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsb_release -d` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @chili555   please find details, lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: "/lib/modules/4.18.0-372.19.1.el8_6.x86_64" I believe that is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux kernel version, not Ubuntu. Please clarify.